# How to include results from related model into queryset?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'd like to show the `likers` of each `post` below that post while the posts are rendered in a for loop. Here are the models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=True)


class PostLike(models.Model):
    post = models.IntegerField(default=0) #post.id
    liker = models.IntegerField(default=0) #user.id of the post liker
```

Then the posts with their likes should be rendered like this:

```
          {% for post in posts %}
          <div class="row">

           <div>{{ post.created |timesince }}</div>
           <div>{{ post.creator }}</div>
           <div>{{ post.title }}</div>
           <div>{{ post.body }}</div> 
           <ul>
              {% for liker in post.likers %}
                   <li><a href="/path/to/profile/{{ liker.name}}">{{ liker.name}}</a></li> 
              {% endfor %}
           </ul>

           {% endfor %}
```

Currently (before deploying likes)  I query posts like this in `views.py`:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(topic=topic_id).order_by("created")
```

I'm wondering what is the best way to put likers in posts query so that they can be used in the template as above?

Comment: The best way is to use ForeignKey with related_name='likers' instead of IntegerField

Comment: Please elaborate your answer. I'm new to django. Not sure to apply your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ForeignKey` instead of `IntegerFiled` in `PostLike` model. Which will give you what you are looking for.

```
class PostLike(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post) #post.id
    liker = models.ForeignKey(User,null=False)
```

now when you access your `Post` object, you can use `postlike_set` to get your all likers.

so in your template you can use

```
{% for liker in post.postlike_set.all %}
    <li><a href="/path/to/profile/{{ liker.name}}">{{ liker.name}}</a></li> 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Sorry, not sure how to do that. Can you elaborate with an example query?

Comment: Well, after applying this and running migrate,  now I get `Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'post.postlike_set.all()'`. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: @Babr just try using post.postlike_set.all in teplate ie remove ().